# JMeter: Does the **Save Responses to a File** storing the data in the cache first when the request is not yet done?

Tags: jmeter

I'm currently testing a 1.5GB download. Does the **Save Responses to a File** storing the data in the cache first when the request is not yet done? Is it possible to configure the JMeter to write the file while receiving the data?

Answer (score 0):

As of [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) the Save Responses to a File listener:

1. Waits for the [full response](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/ResultSaver.java#L202) to arrive to JMeter
2. Writes it using BufferedOutpuStream via [JOrphanUtils.write()](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/src/jorphan/src/main/java/org/apache/jorphan/util/JOrphanUtils.java#L551) function

It's not possible to easily amend this behaviour unless you're willing to [write a custom plugin for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html)

I can suggest a better option: instead of saving the whole file you could:

1. Tick `Save response as MD5 hash?` box under "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler

   [image]
2. The downloaded file integrity can be checked using [MD5Hex Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion)

   [image]

The point is that same files have the same MD5 checksum, if the downloaded file's checksum will be different - it means that the file content differs and MD5Hex Assertion will fail the associated Sampler.

As a bonus, this trick will greatly reduce JMeter's memory consumption and you will be able to conduct higher load from the same machine.

More information on JMeter Assertions concept: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)